# scraping rss feed doesn't return any results using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using **Scrapy** to scrape a page, I tried many times and I am convinced that the following doesn't work (in the shell) and returns empty result:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="itemtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
```

this is where in chrome console, this brings me the expected result:

```
$x('//*[@class="itemtitle"]/a/text()')[0]
```

I checked the robot.txt for the target url and found out the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /~a/
```

I am wondering if it is not allowed to scrape it.

So my specific question is that is it possible to prevent robots from scraping on certain pages? if not what can be wrong with my code, that bring empty result in Scrapy shell.

Comment: You should link the actual page. Maybe the feed is loaded in with javascript. Not sure if scrapy respects robots.txt, but it's never impossible to scrape anything.

Comment: Scrapy spider respects the robots.txt. Of course it can be turned off. But I am doing this in scrapy shell, where there is no setting as far as i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check source HTML (usually `Ctrl+U` in a browser). You need:

```
response.xpath('//item/title/text()').extract()
```